# Typing Map where key and value types are related

Tags: flutter, dart, dictionary, types

Is there a way of typing a map whose keys and values are of the same type individually, but are of different types to other keys and values in the map? For example, this would allow

```dart
final foo = {
  'stringKey': 'stringValue',
  1: 2,
  true: false,
}
```

and would not allow

```dart
final bar = {
  'stringKey': 2,
  1: false,
  true: 'stringValue',
}
```

My use case is a wrapper for shared preferences, where implementation is hidden, and an enum

```dart
enum PersistantData<T> {
  data1<int>,
  data2<String>,
  ...
}
```

which encapsulates the data that the rest of the app can ask for/set is exposed, along with a class which takes care of persistance and provides access to the values of the different data. Inside the class is a map which implements the store, and has keys of `PersistantData` members and values of the persistant data, which are of type `PersistantDataValue<T, S>`, `S` being the primative data type which is passed to shared_preferences. The type of the `PersistantData` keys relate to the type of the corresponding persistant data value, consistent with how `T` is used above. I was hoping this could be indicated through generics, e.g.

```dart
final _store = <PersistantData<T>, PersistantDataValue<T, S>>{
  ...
}
```

but that didn't work (a misuse of generic types I suppose). A typedef didn't help either, I tried

```dart
typedef PersistantDataStore<T, S>
    = Map<PersistantData<T>, PersistantDataValue<T, S>>;
```

but that didn't quite work - given `T` and `S` can vary between entries they both need to be declared as dynamic, and then on further experimentation neither the compiler nor vscode's linter got upset when `T` was inconsistent between `PersistantData` and `PersistantDataValue`.

Is there a way of achieving this, or could a different approach be taken to get better type handling?

Comment: It loses the meaning of Map

Comment: @bakboem possibly, I'd argue that the structure is still there (moreso in my use case than in the example I provided which was more for clarity). Futhermore, if the compiler were aware of this type constraint, it'd come with the benefit of knowing the type of the value you're getting from the map by the type of key you access it with. If a map is inappropriate here, is there an alternate structure you'd suggest? Or could you propose how to build a class which has the benefits of "type-of-key-in, same-type-of-value-out"?

Comment: If the key is not the same type, how to loop? iteration? traversal? so I don't think it's good advice

Comment: Maybe a list of objects where the object class does the checking of the pair types...depends if a list of objects meets your use case requirements.

Comment: @GrahamD thanks, please could you say more about what you have in mind? I don't see how that avoids the issue?

Comment: @bakboem fair point, there's more to maps than keys and values I guess, and this is a somewhat niche case.

Comment: I think I don't understand your use case sufficiently. I presume you are storing the persisted data and then retrieving it. So my question would be, why can't you ensure that the data stored is of the correct type pair before you store it.

Comment: @GrahamD gotcha, you're right that that can be ensured, but only by careful checking right? Unless I'm misunderstanding you. The issue is more that the store could be set up incorrectly in the first place - it'd be nice if there was something in the type system stopping me from creating an entry like PersistantData<T>: PersistantDataValue<S, U> in the map.

Comment: I'm a kiss kinda guy. I don't really understand why you have a 'wrapper' involving enums. Personally I'm pretty sure I can guarantee the content and type I write to my shared prefs. Just as I can for what I write to my database. Don't think I can help you.

Comment: How about you either have a List<Map> of whatever type map you want or a Map<String, Map> with the internal map type you need...those internal maps can be any type of map, as values of the outer map...but you can't mix key types or value types in same map.

Comment: @jbryanh yes, that'd work - thanks. I'll write up an answer unless you wanted to provide one.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, it's an abuse of the concept of a map, but you can achieve it by building the map "bottom up" by starting with a typedef

```dart
typedef linkedMapEntry<T, S> = MapEntry<Foo<T>, Bar<T, S>>;
```

then declaring the map entries as instances of `linkedMapEntry`, before building the final map out of them.